# Processing Modeler QGIS Issues With Interpolation Step

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to interpolate **Sampled Points** with **IDW Interpolation** in the QGIS processing modeler.  For some reason I am not able to select the **Sampled Points** with the **IDW Interpolation**.  Anyone know why that would happen? 
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, the small "123"-Box (letting you choose the input source) is missing here. You can report this at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues if not already done so.